# Redundant generic arguments?

Tags: c#, generics

I am building a entity Repository and I have an interface, `IIdentifiable<T>`.  So entities which are identified by Guids, for example, implement `IIdentifiable<Guid> with public Guid Id { get; }`.  So far, so good.

I have an interface of `IRepository<T, TIdentifier> where T : IIdentifiable<TIdentifier>`.

It seems to me that the TIdentifier generic argument is redundant, because that already information is held in the generic argument of T.  Is there any way I can have a cleaner implementation of IRepository, where I only have to specify T in my business code?

I'm after something like `'IRepository<T> where T : IIdentifiable<T.GenericArgs[0]>`.

I doubt this is possible, but just thought I'd ask.  Maybe the new C# 4 stuff has something for this this?

Answer (score 2):

There's no constraint on `T` which requires it to be a generic.  And there's nothing which prevents a class from implementing `IIdentifiable<T1>`, `IIdentifiable<T2>`, ... `IIdentifiable<Tn>`, so even some syntax saying "the first argument of the `IIdentifiable'1` interface implemented by `T`" wouldn't be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `IIdentifiable` that has `object Id { get; }` then have `IIdentifiable<T> : IIDentifiable` with a generic Id property.

Then you can reduce the number of generic arguments to 1 like so:

```
IRepository<T> where T : IIdentifiable
```

In practice you would then use `IRepository<X>` with `X : IIdentifiable<Guid>`

This assumes that your IRepository is mainly interested in the ability of T to have a key and isn't focused on the specific type of key.

Comment: The thing is that the generic Id property would hide the non-generic one

Comment: Well, since they're interfaces it's not 'really' hiding. Presumably the non-generic explicit implementation will just call the generic Id property

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to be able to specify a contraint, based on the assumption that type has already satisfied that contraint, putting the compiler into a logical paradox.

Also, your plan makes `TIdentifier` unknown within `IRepository` which, I assume it's going to need to know.